# Getting an extra post's meta data?

Tags: posts, date

I seem to be getting an extra post's data when calling `get_the_time('Y');` 
I only have 2 posts, but I seem to be getting 3 dates? I have no idea why.

Here's the code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'celebrity');
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $get_year[] = get_the_time('Y'); 
        foreach($get_year as $year) {
          echo $year;
        }
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This outputs:
"2013 2013 2013"

It seems to only be doing this when I do a `foreach` if I just `echo get_the_time` it works fine, outputting two "2013".

The point of this code is that I just want a list of years that have posts. My plan was to just stick each occurrence of the year into an array, use `array_unique()` and echo out each year. There will probably be better ways to do this, I'm open to suggestion but this was the first thing that came to mind.

So to recap, I seem to be getting 3 dates instead of 2 when I only have 2 posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your array ***and*** iterating over it at each iteration of the outer Loop. Think about what happens.

## First iteration of the outer loop

`$get_year` becomes `array('2012')` and you iterate over it `echo`ing "2012".

## Second iteration

`$get_year` becomes `array('2012',2013')` and you iterate over it `echo`ing "2012" and "2013".

Do you see what happened? You have `echo`ed the same data twice. You are `echo`ing the partially constructed `$get_year` array. The more posts you have the bigger the problem will become and I would not be surprised if it crashed the browser eventually.

Pull that `foreach` out of the other loop so that you only iterate over it once-- ***after it is has been completely constructed***.

```
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while($loop->have_posts()) {
  $loop->the_post(); 
  $get_year[] = get_the_time('Y'); 
}
foreach($get_year as $year) {
  echo $year;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Ahh.. Damn loops. Thanks man, you've helped me a lot on here :)

Comment: p.s I think I'm going to stop using : for now and stick with curly braces, as I might have caught that sooner.

Comment: Yes, don't use that "alternative" control structure syntax. It is nothing but unreadable and prone to error, and tends to encourage poorly or nonsensically formatted code to boot. I can't stand it.